# How to delete "" from a list of character vectors

Tags: r, string

I have a list of character vectors, where some elements are actual strings, such as "FA" and "EX". However, some others are just "". I want to delete these.

```
list1 <- c("FA", "EX", "")
list2 <- c("FA")
list3 <- c("")
list <- list(list1, list2, list3)

> list
[[1]]
[1] "FA" "EX" ""  

[[2]]
[1] "FA"

[[3]]
[1] ""
```

Should then be

```
[[1]]
[1] "FA" "EX"  

[[2]]
[1] "FA"
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Could any of the listed vectors consist of just two or more zero-length strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
lapply(list[list!=''], function(x) x[x!=''])
```