# R: Removing blanks from the list

Tags: r

I'm wondering if there is any way to remove blanks from the list.
As far as I've searched, I found out that there are many Q&As for removing
the whole element from the list, but couldn't find the one regarding
a specific component of the element.

To be specific, the list now I'm working with looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "1" ""  ""  "2" ""  ""  "3"

[[2]]
[1] "weak"

[[3]]
[1] "22" "33"

[[4]]
[1] "44"  "34p" "45"
```

From above, you can find " ", which should be removed.
I've tried different commands like

```
text.words.bl <- text.words.ll[-which(text.words.ll==" ")]
text.words.bl <- text.words.ll[!sapply(text.words.ll, is.null)]
```

etc, but seems like "  "s in [[1]] of the list still remains.

Is it impossible to apply commands to small pieces in each element of the list?
(e.g. 1, 2, weak, 22, 33... respectively)

I've used "lapply" function to run specific commands to each elements,
and it seemed like those lapply commands all worked....

JY

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete "" from a list of character vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29038460/how-to-delete-from-a-list-of-character-vectors)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `%in%`, but negate it with `!`:

```
## Sample data:
L <- list(c(1, 2, "", "", 4), c(1, "", "", 2), c("", "", 3))
L
# [[1]]
# [1] "1" "2" ""  ""  "4"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "1" ""  ""  "2"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] ""  ""  "3"
```

The replacement:

```
lapply(L, function(x) x[!x %in% ""])
# [[1]]
# [1] "1" "2" "4"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "1" "2"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "3"
```

Obviously, assign the output to "L" if you want to overwrite the original dataset:

```
L[] <- lapply(L, function(x) x[!x %in% ""])
```

Comment: I think you could just use `!=` here for better efficiency

Answer (score 6):

Another way would be to use `nchar()`. I borrowed `L` from @Ananda Mahto.

```
lapply(L, function(x) x[nchar(x) >= 1])

#[[1]]
#[1] "1" "2" "4"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "1" "2"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "3"
```

Comment: As I re-read their question, I wonder if they have blanks that are more than one space. +1 for this alternative though :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thank you. :) If we have more information we'd be able to suggest precise solutions. +1 back to you.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, thnx so much! but just wondering-- what do you think is the reason that commands using simple lapply(ex. text.words.ll[!lapply(text.words.ll, is.null)] ) didn't get applied to every single items?

Comment: @prejay10 I am not sure if `is.null` is the way to go. You may want to compare the following. `x <- ""; is.null(x)` and `y <- NULL; is.null(y)`.